# IE document mode works only when users switches document modes

Tags: internet-explorer, jsp, twitter-bootstrap

My issue is as following

1. I have added IE meta tag  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">`
2. IE version is 8
3. When page loads, Document mode is set to 8 but UI on the page doesnt not look good especially bootstrap dropdowns including font awesome images.
4. when user switches the document mode to 7 and again change the mode to 8 then UI looks good.
5. we are still using iframes/frameset but this can not be changed

Why do user has to explicitly switch and change the mode even though document mode shown when page load is correct? what is the work around for this?

any help pointers will be a great help

Comment: Do you also have a DTD correctly placed into your file? Notice, that the `x-ua-compatible` must be placed before anything which could amend the document mode, i.e. before any `script`, `link` or `style` tag and rather even before other `meta`s.

Comment: yes we do have  <!doctype html>

Comment: The question was: is it correctly placed? It should be on the very first line in a file, without any preceeding characters.

Comment: Thank you Teemu. Since we were using Iframes and frameset, and much more complex structure it was hard to find starting point. But your comment confirmed that our tag is not in the right place. Issue is resolved. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the meta tag to the first line.